# Avoid inserting duplicates when using autoincrementing index

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, unique-constraint, unique-index

I have a query:

```
INSERT INTO tweet_hashtags(hashtag_id, tweet_id)
VALUES(1, 1) 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING 
RETURNING id
```

which work fine and inserts with `id = 1`, but when there is a duplicate let's say another `(1, 1)` it inserts with an `id = 2`. I want to prevent this from happening and I read that I can do `ON CONFLICT (col_name)` but that doesn't really help because I need to check for two values at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on conflict clause requires a unique constraint or index on the set of columns that you want to be unique - and it looks like you don't have that in place.

You can set it when you create table table:

```
create table tweet_hashtags(
    id serial primary key, 
    hashtag_id int, 
    tweet_id int, 
    unique (hashtag_id, tweet_id)
);
```

Or, if the table already exists, you can create a unique index (but you need to get rid of the duplicates first):

```
create unique index idx_tweet_hashtags on tweet_hashtags(hashtag_id, tweet_id);
```

Then your query should just work:

```
insert into tweet_hashtags(hashtag_id, tweet_id)
values(1, 1) 
on conflict (hashtag_id, tweet_id) do nothing 
returning id
```

Specifying the conflict target makes the intent clearer and should be generally preferred (although it is not mandatory with `do nothing`).

Note that the query returns nothing when the insert is skipped (that is, the existing `id` is not returned).

Here is a [demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46e6dab43dde19468b815d8370c05cfe) that demonstrates the behavior with and without the unique index.